# Standarts for email source code

Tags: email

I am looking for standarts for email source code, just to know how to generate it using php.

My specific problem is with **multipart/mixed** email. 
The email's subject is in cyrilic and when I am sending email it arives without errors, but subject of email can't be read. There is some problem with encoding.

Here is my email header:

```
    From: no-reply@sample.eu\n
    Reply-To: no-reply@sample.eu\n
    Cc:\n
    Bcc:\n
    X-Priority: 1 (Highest)\n
    X-Mailer: PHP/5.3.29\n
    MIME-Version: 1.0\n
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n
    boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x3865d75cb66632b12851874c2aafd492x"\n
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The email standard is pretty large, but you should be able to work through the broad picture in a few days. The [wikipedia page for email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_format) has links to all the RFC standards for the message format. It also has a broad overview of the format.

The standard for the main format is defined [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). Mime/multimedia attachments are covered [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) and [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2049).

IMHO, I would try to find a library to deal with this sort of stuff. It's easy to make mistakes when you are formatting this on your own. [Here is one in PEAR](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php) that seems to do what you need.

Or, instead of trying to figure out how to do this in php, try to use a language with better unicode support like [Python3](https://www.python.org/) or [Perl5](https://www.perl.org/) that actually does this for you automatically. You'll waste a lot less time.